# Can someone explain pointer in C language for me?

Tags: c

I'm mostly using `Javascript` so the pointer doesn't exist in this language (on the surface, I guess, I heard somewhere it still does the pointer thing behind the scene).

But I have a course that I'm learning C program right now, I'm kind of getting an idea of the pointer, which points to the address of the variables, I guess.

But I'm getting confused with when are we using, for example:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

Are there any differences between `Node* next`, `Node * next` and `Node *next`? Or they are the same? If it doesn't the same, why they are using it that way, I can't quite wrap my head around this.

Comment: There is no difference between those three notations.  C is not white-space sensitive.

Comment: They're all the same. Personally, I typically use `Node *next;` to be clear (the `*` attaches to the name, not the type; if you declare `Node *a, b;`, `a` is a pointer to `Node`, `b` is a raw `Node` struct, and using `Node* a, b;` may mislead people to think *both* are pointers, even though `b` remains a non-pointer), but all of them mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, technically `b` isn't a `struct`, but an object.   =P

Comment: Thanks for your guys' comment. So they are the same. The course just explains what the pointer is and then they start using it differently each time, which makes me a little bit confused.

Comment: note that most devs will hate `Node * next` - just becasue

Comment: About clarity and style: what @ShadowRanger says: `Node* a, b;` does not define two pointer variables, so although the syntax is legal, it is undesirable IMO.